rendered image has jaggedered edges
I am trying to render the image of a jersey. The jersey looks decent.

however when i render it there are lots of issue with jaggered edges and somehow bad render...?

I added sub division surface modifier but it doesnt seem to be solving the issue.

the file can be found here
drive link to the file

hello, maybe the image is simply too low res?

its 1920 x 1920

It's the model that is too low res, not the image. I think if you are not happy about the model, you should either remodel it(simulate it in higher resolution) or attempt to fix it - maybe sculpting after subdividing could help. This does not seem to have anything to do with rendering. It's about the geometry that is being rendered.
